# Illustrator: line breaks vs paragraph breaks

Tags: adobe-illustrator, adobe-indesign, typography, typesetting

When working with area text in Illustrator, I sometimes use the **space after** option. This makes it more obvious when I create a line break, as illustrator automatically inserts a paragraph break as well.

Is there a way to create a simple line break, without having to *space* or *tab* your way to the end of the line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are called **soft returns** (or forced line breaks) and are achieved via <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>, as opposed to the usual **hard returns** achieved with a simple <kbd>ENTER</kbd> key.

Note that inserting a soft return **does not end** a paragraph like a hard return does. You can insert as many soft returns as you need and you are still in the same paragraph. This means only hard returns (simple <kbd>ENTER</kbd>'s) are followed by the "space after" paragraph setting.

Additionally, hitting <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> will show/hide these hidden (non-printing) characters, so you always know where you have soft/hard returns, spaces, tabs, etc.

[image: soft hard return]

Comment: Ah, for some reason I didn't think to try that!

Comment: This shortcut also works in InDesign and even MS Word, etc. You should never have to _space_ or _tab_ your way to the next line, there are "cleaner" ways to play with your text.